# TextInputEditText - CompoundDrawable is not centered

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-textinputedittext, compound-drawables

Im trying to add a suffix to my TextInputEditText by creating a TextDrawable then setting that using `compoundDrawable`. Everything is going fairly well except the drawable gets clipped outside to right of the component. What could be causing this? So far ive tried changing the font size but that is not doing any difference... Is the drawable too wide or what?

[image]

The String is `"kr/månad"` and as you can see it is clipped..

**XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutTheme">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/text_input_edit_text"
        style="@style/TextInputEditTextStyle" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**COMPONENT CODE**

```
  textInputEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, TextDrawable(unitText), null)
```

**TEXTDRAWABLE**

```
class TextDrawable(private val text: String?) : Drawable() {

    private val paint: Paint

    init {
        paint = Paint()
        paint.color = Color.BLACK
        paint.textSize = 44f
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        paint.isFakeBoldText = true
        paint.typeface = Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL)
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        text?.let { text ->
            canvas.drawText(text, 0f, 0f, paint)
        }
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {
        paint.alpha = alpha
    }

    override fun setColorFilter(cf: ColorFilter?) {
        paint.colorFilter = cf
    }

    override fun getOpacity(): Int {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work well with default `EditText`?

Comment: @ADM I do not know. But I want to use the material components!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
class TextDrawable(private val text: String?) : Drawable() {

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.BLACK
        textSize = 44f
        isAntiAlias = true
        isFakeBoldText = true
        typeface = Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", Typeface.NORMAL)
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        setBounds(0, 0, measureText(text).toInt(), 0)
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        text?.let { text ->
            canvas.drawText(text, 0f, 0f, paint)
        }
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {
        paint.alpha = alpha
    }

    override fun setColorFilter(cf: ColorFilter?) {
        paint.colorFilter = cf
    }

    override fun getOpacity(): Int {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    }
}
```

*The difference is in two lines.* I removed this

```
paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
```

and added this:

```
setBounds(0, 0, measureText(text).toInt(), 0)
```

[image: Code Result]

Comment: The problem was because i had not setBounds which seems to be a must in order for `setCompoundDrawables()` to calculate and center the text.